# Data missmatch between web3.js 1.0 and Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm mew to Ethereum/Solidity/Web3.js. I'm trying to use web3.js web.eth.sendsendTransaction() method in order to run a function in a deployed contract on a private chain.

The function I try to execute is:

```
contract Matematicas{
    uint256 ultimaSuma;
    uint256 ultimaMultiplicacion;
    uint256 contador;
    uint256 factorA;
    uint256 factorB;
    uint256 sumandoA;
    uint256 sumandoB;
    bytes datosMensaje;...
    
    function multiplica(uint256 a, uint256 b) public{
        datosMensaje=msg.data;
        factorA=a;
        factorB=b;
        ultimaMultiplicacion=(a*b);
    }
... 
}
```

I call multiplica from Mist browser runnig the following JavaScript code:

```
var contracAddress="0xXXXXXXXX";
var contractABI=[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"a","type":"uint256"},{"name":"b","type":"uint256"}],"name":"multiplica","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},...];
var functionABI=$.grep(contractABITercero,function(metodo,index){ return metodo.name=='multiplica';});
functionABI=abiDelaFuncion[0];
var abiByteCode= web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall(functionABI,[document.getElementById('firstNumber').value,document.getElementById('secondNumber').value]);
var transactionObject={from:"0xxxxxxxxxx",to:contractAddress,data:abiByteCode, gas:10000000};
web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject, function(error,hash){......});
```

If I set firstNumber=1000 and secondNumber=2000 then abiByteCodes happens to be:

```
0x38e836df00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003e800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000007d0
```

0x38e836df is the sha of the fuction signature, that is correct;

03e8 is hexadecimal for 1000(firstNumber) right

07d0 is hex for 2000(secondNumber) ok

But data stored in the block chain is:

```
datosMensaje: 0x38e836df0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**9e0**3e80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000**9e0**7d0

factorA:
8520680 (0x8203E8)

factorB:
8521680 (0x8207D0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using geth 1.7.3 and Mist 0.9.2 on a Windows 10 64 bit desktop.

P.S. I know there are other ways to call contract functions like instantiating the contract via new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress) but I'm thinking about a project that would require to use the sendTransaction()  method

Comment: Assuming you copy and pasted your code, you misspelled "contractAddress" on the first line: `var contracAddress="0xXXXXXXXX";` Your `transactionObject` has an empty `to` field as a result.

Comment: Thank hoy Adam. In the actual Code the true address is especified I just wrote here 0xXxxx...  to avoid copying the hole number

Comment: I wasn’t referring to the value. I was referring to the variable name. You’re missing a t in “contractAddress”. It is spelled correctly (and, hence, a different variable) when set in the transactionObject.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an error in how remix IDE shows values in the debug tab. If I recover the data from the blockchain using web3.js ver 1.0 method getStorageAt(address,key) I get the expected values.